# Spring Boot + Cloud Firestore Integration Tests

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, google-cloud-firestore

I have written unit tests for my service, repository and controller for adding and retrieving data from a Cloud Firestore database, mocking the addition and retrieval of data from a mock firestore object. However, I want to write and retrieve actual data from an actual Cloud Firestore instance, without interacting with my firestore instances in my staging and production environments. Is there any way of creating a local development instance of Cloud Firestore?

Answer (score 1):

> mocking the addition and retrieval of data from a mock Firestore object.

There is no way you can get the data only from a mock `Firestore` object. So instead of mocking only the Firestore object, you'll have to also mock any other `CollectionReference` or `DocumentReference` object that is returned as a result of calling `collection()` or `document()` in your chain. For instance, if you call `collection()` on your `Firestore` object, the object that is returned is a `CollectionReference` object which should be mocked. Furthermore, if you call then in turn `document()` on the resulted `CollectionReference` object, the object that is returned is of type `DocumentReference`, which should also be mocked. So this mock operation should be done for every new such method call.

This is happening because the mocks do **not** know how to generate more mock objects for the methods on that mock. As explained above, you have to tell it what to return for each method call individually.